# Generic extension method hides non-generic method

Tags: c#, .net, generics

When I have a generic extension method, with the same name as a non-generic extension method, the generic extension method hides the non-generic method.
However, if I would use non-generic methods in both cases, it would not hide.

Why is this different than regular overloading?
And why is the C# compiler even trying to use Ext1 in the case below when IA does not even inherit from IB which is the type constraint. Does the C# not care about type constraints when finding extension methods?

The below code won't even compile, as it complains about A cannot be implicitly converted to IB.

```
public interface IA {}
public interface IB {}
public interface IB1 : IB {}
public interface IB2 : IB {}

public class A : IA {}
public class B1 : IB1 {}
public class B2 : IB2 {}

public static class Ext1
{
    public static string WithSomething<T>(this T builder)
        where T : IB
    {
        return "Ext1";
    }
}

public static class Ext2
{
    public static string WithSomething(this IA builder)
    {
        return "Ext2";
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class ExtensionTests
{
    [Test]
    public void ShouldUseExt1()
    {
        var actual = new B1().WithSomething();
        Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo("Ext1"));
    }

    [Test]
    public void ShouldUseExt2()
    {
        var actual = new A().WithSomething();
        Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo("Ext2"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to know why the overloading is done this way, or do you want a solution to your coding problem?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. I know I can use "Ext1.WithSomething(new A())", e.g. not use as extension method. A real fix would require a .NET patch I guess. So I'm wondering why the compiler does this. It seems kinda dumb and non-intelligent.

Comment: See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx for about a hundred people telling me I'm wrong that this is a sensible rule.

Comment: Extension methods are very detrimental to program readability, you only use them when you've got your back against the wall and cannot add a method to a class that you cannot possibly modify.  So if you really have to then you always make it explicit which particular class you extend.  You are hoping that the C# compiler infers that it should use the extension method for IA.  The C# team made no bones about that.  There's very little hope that the reader of the program can see the same indirection the find the method back.  So the C# team just forbade it.  Excellent decision.